# What is the restriction on $k$, for the $k$th composite residuosity problem to be hard?

Tags: provable-security, quadratic-residuosity

The paper [“Residuosity Problem and Its Applications to Cryptography”](http://coitweb.uncc.edu/~yzheng/publications/files/ieiceE71-8b.pdf) considers the exponent to be an odd integer.

When $k = 2$, it is called the quadratic residuosity problem (mod $n$, where $n$ is composite) which is hard and can be solved if the factorization of n is known.

What happens to the $k$th residuosity problem if $k$ is an even integer $> 2$?

Comment: If the factorization of $n$ is known, the higher residuosity problem modulo $n$ can be easily solved.  The other direction is unknown.

Comment: You may take a look at http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00145-016-9229-5 when $k$ is a power of $2$.